# Generate data-bound FormView fields on-the-fly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding, formview

I have an existing ASP.NET 3.5 application with a webform containing a FormView control used to perform CRUD operations on a domain object.  A new requirement adds some dynamic content to the domain object that needs to be reflected in the FormView.  This means that I need to generate those controls on-the-fly based on the bound object.

I am using an ObjectDataSource for the FormView that returns the domain object for binding.  The domain object will now have a property that returns a collection of Section objects with each Section containing a list of Questions.  In the middle of my form, I need to display each section with the list of questions and a textbox that allows the user to input the answer.

I am able to generate the UI a number of different ways but I have yet to find a way that includes data for the dynamic fields when the page is posted back.  Because I won't know the 'schema' until the FormView is data-bound, I'm wondering if I'm too late in the pipeline for postback data to be handled properly.

What is the best way for me to generate these fields so the data is posted back correctly?

**UPDATE**

I'm still looking for the best way to accomplish this task but I've found a solution that at least works.  In short, I am creating the dynamic content in the FormView's DataBound event handler because this is the first place in the pipeline that I can always get references to the FormView's controls.  Then I follow Muhammed's suggestion and pull the values right out of the Request.Form collection and put them into the EventArgs objects in the FormView's ItemInserting and ItemUpdating handlers.

This isn't so straight forward as each control has to have a unique ID that I can then use to locate the value - which isn't so bad. However, I had to implement custom logic in the data source to then map these values into the data-bound object.

All-in-all, not too bad but certainly not something I'd want to duplicate in other solutions so I'm hoping there's still a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get the value from the dynamic generated field, you should  get it from the `Request.Form` collection and pass it into the `ItemInserting` event of FormView. e.g.

```
 protected void frmAsset_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
 {
   e.Values["FieldName"] =    Request.Form[ControlClientID];
 }
```

Please note, your controls should be recreated on postback to get the value.

Comment: Yea, the problem is when to recreate the controls. It appears that I can't get a reference to the controls in the FormView until the Load event and by then the postback data has already been restored to the control tree. Since the generated controls aren't in the control tree, the values are lost.

Comment: That's why I have recommend you to get value from Request.Form Collection.